# NetBeans 6.8 C++, files are being written and read in the wrong directory

Tags: file, netbeans, filepath, writefile

When i run my project with the "Run main project" mode, my program writes the .txt file to my /home directory. I found this extremely odd, so I ran the program with "Debug main project" mode and it wrote the .txt file to the project directory. Is there a setting in options that will fix this so both modes will write the file to the project directory?

I have tried to make new projects with the same results

Answer (score 0):

Most C++ projects in Netbeans have a Debug and Release configuration. Both of these may have different settings for running the program and should be checked to see if one of them specifies a "run directory".

If you right click on the root of the project tree and select properties, you will notice a drop-down at the top for "Configuration" that will allow you two switch between the two groups of settings.
[image]

Comment: I set both configurations to the same run directory and no dice.... it still writes the file to my /home directory.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what exactly is set for the run directory?

Comment: Perhaps check the output paths in the Linker category, maybe one is less deeply nested than the other? I'm grasping here :)

Comment: One more thing to try, use your favorite diff program to compare Makefile-Debug.mk and Makefile-Release.mk and see if anything jumps out at you.

Comment: I'll keep thinking about it then. Good luck.

Comment: did you have any more ideas? I really like the netbeans IDE

Comment: It's the IDE I use at work and at home. Perhaps you could add some code to the question area that shows how you are setting up the file for output.